# PHPMailer won't work with mail.privateemail.com account

Tags: php, email, server, phpmailer

I'm very nearly finished with the website I've been working on for 6 months. It's just come time to deploy to the server.

Unfortunately, i can't get emails to send. Previously I was always testing either locally, or on my personal test server, sending emails with phpmailer and my netfirms email account. Now I'm on the new server, sending with my netfirms account works just fine, but not with the client's namecheap email, through mail.privateemail.com. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;


function sendFormEmail($mail, $to, $subject, $senderName, $senderEmail, $message, $sendCopy) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = random_string(50);
     $subject = filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $senderName = filter_var($senderName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $senderEmail = filter_var($senderEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
     $message = filter_var($_POST['body'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.privateemail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;    
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'my-email';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'my-pass';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('webmaster@mysite.com', 'mysite.com'); 
        $mail->addAddress('my-email', 'me');     
        $mail->addReplyTo($senderEmail, $senderName);

        $mail->Subject = "mysite.com: " . $subject;
        $mail->Body    = "<h1>You've received a message through the contact form at mysite.com: </h1><br><p style='white-space: pre-wrap;'>" . $message . "</p>";
        $mail->AltBody = "You've received a message through the contact form at mysite.com: " . $message;

        if($mail->send()) {
         return "wooho!";
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps returning that the function went through, but no emails. If I change only the host, username, password, and port to those of my netfirms email, it works perfectly. I've also signed into this email address using a third party client to verify I have the correct server settings, and that worked just fine.

Here is the phpmailer debug output:

```
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 PrivateEmail.com Mail Node 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mysite.com 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mta2.ox.privateemail.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 81788928 250-ETRN 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2016-01-22 23:13:47  CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mysite.com 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mta2.ox.privateemail.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 81788928 250-ETRN 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: d2VibWFzdGVyQGNocmlzY29tcG9zZXMuY29t 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: U3VwM3ItUzNjcjN0 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with . 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 22 Jan 
2016 18:13:46 -0500 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: me 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: "mysite.com" 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: me 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: mysite.com: test 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <57602f8384a430fc72ff9ba41db09f97@mysite.com> 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.13 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_57602f8384a430fc72ff9ba41db09f97" 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format. 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_57602f8384a430fc72ff9ba41db09f97 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: You've received a message through the contact form at mysite.com: test 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_57602f8384a430fc72ff9ba41db09f97 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER:
You've received a message through the contact form at mysite.com:

test

2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2016-01-22 23:13:47   CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_57602f8384a430fc72ff9ba41db09f97-- 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8B426600ED 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-01-22 23:13:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I've been at this for quite awhile and am really out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I know the client could just make a gmail account and we could probably send through that just fine. I'd just really like to use the email address they paid for, if possible. Starting to really dislike namecheap.

Comment: Try formatting the debug output so that it can be easily read.

Comment: done! should be good  now

Comment: That debug output shows a successful delivery to that mail server, so PHPMailer's involvement is over. You should read the mail server's log to see what happened to the message after that.

Comment: Thank you! Knowing where to look is all I need.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same problem in the future, there is a dedicated description on the Namecheap site here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9751/31/how-to-configure-php-mailsmtp-authentication-for-different-cms

The key difference compared to the default config in my case was that I had to **change the port to 587** (like this `$mail->Port = 587;`) and it was working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't get errors from the SMTP server, the email is sent
but it doesn't reach the recipient mailbox. I think the email was classified as spam, did you configured the SPF record correctly? On my experience this is the most common problem...
For example if your production site is mysite.com and the SMTP server domain is privateemail.com, on your mysite.com DNS records you have to add a TXT record like this:

```
mysite.com.  TXT  v=spf1 include:privateemail.com +a +mx ~all
```

I hope this can help

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely try that. For now I've got it just configured to send from my own hosting provider's email but show to the recipient that it was sent from the other one. Definitely very displeased with namecheap. You've got to pay for an email address if you're not using their hosting, and when you do, there's a bunch of configuration to do on your hosting side.

Using Netfirms I got a free email address that actually worked.